# Select from mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Since this can not be done like :

```
select * from (call my_stored_procedure(params));
```

Is there any alternative for the above statement ?

Comment: why not put all the query inside the stored procedure?

Comment: Yeah, I even tried to do that. I could not manipulate the result set generated from query for the next query.

Comment: What kind of manipulation do you need? Both answers are correct for your situation. Function is seemd to be some kind of 'named' peace of code which query executes each time function is called. Insert from SP requires temporary table or table variable, executes ones and make possible further manipulations with data. Which one better suits your requirement for "manipulation"? Just to clarify which of two right answers is more right :-)

Answer (score 1):

A procedure could return multiple result sets, each with its own schema. It's not suitable for using in a SELECT statement.

User-defined function could be an option. Here's an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CubicVolume
 -- Input dimensions in centimeters
 (@CubeLength decimal(4,1), @CubeWidth decimal(4,1),@CubeHeight decimal(4,1) )
  RETURNS decimal(12,3) -- Cubic Centimeters.
  AS
  BEGIN
   RETURN ( @CubeLength * @CubeWidth * @CubeHeight )
 END
```

more on this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175085%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table variable and insert sp values into it, like :

```
Declare @t table
(
  --column numbers will be equals to the numbers return by SP
)
Insert Into @t
call my_stored_procedure(params)

Select * From @t
```